# Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel not returning proper id values when multipal rows are checked in the grid

Tags: javascript, extjs3

im using extjs3 . my problem is im loading the store from server side using ajax . as follows

```js
var store_dept = new Ext.data.JsonStore({              
                totalProperty:'totalcount',
                root:'rows_dept',   
                autoLoad:true,
                url: '<%=getResultURL.toString()%>',  
                fields:[

                        { name:'name'},
                        { name:'id'},
                        { name:'address'}
                      ] 

             });

var sm_dept = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel(

                        {
                            singleSelect: false,
                            checkOnly: false,
                            listeners: {

                                selectionchange: function(sm_dept) {


                                }
                            }
                        }

                );
```

now  im getting the response so im formatting it in renderer column as

```js
function renderBufferResult_dept(value, p, record){

     return String.format('<div style="white-space:normal !important;"><b>{1}</b><br/>{3}<br/>{2}<br/></div>',value,record.data.name,record.data.address,record.data.id);
 }
```

the grid code is :

```js
 var  grid_dept= new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                id:'resgriddept',               
                width:210,
                height:300,
                title:'Additional Notification',
                store: store_dept,
                trackMouseOver:false,
                disableSelection:true,
                loadMask: true,
                sm:sm_dept,
                // grid columns
                columns:[
                        sm_dept, 
                         {                
                    header: "Details",
                    dataIndex: 'id',
                    width:210,                
                    sortable: true,
                    renderer:renderBufferResult_dept
                }
                ] ,

               buttons: [
                         {
                             text:'Export To Excel',
                             handler: function()
                            {


                                if(property_list!=''){
                                    /* var prop_list='';
                                    for(var i=0 ;i<sm.selections.getCount();i++){
                                        prop_list =prop_list+ sm.selections.get(i).data.id+',';

                                    } */
                                    window.open('<%=getxlFileURL%>'+'&id_list='+property_list);

                                }else{
                                    alert('Select propert to Export');
                                }
                            }


                         },{

                             text:'Generate Letter',
                             handler: function()
                            {



                                       var dept_id_list = '0,';
                                      if(sm_dept.selections.getCount()>0){
                                          alert('cont select');
                                        for(var j=0 ;j<sm_dept.selections.getCount();j++){
                                            alert("id "+sm_dept.selections.get(j).data.id);
                                            dept_id_list = dept_id_list+sm_dept.selections.get(j).data.id+',';
                                            alert('id with templist '+dept_id_list);
                                        }
                                     }  
                                        window.open('<%=getreportsURL%>'+'&id_list='+property_list+'&dept_id_list='+dept_id_list);


                            } 

                         }],
              buttonAlign:'center'

             });//End Of Grid
             // render it    
             grid_dept.render('res-grid-dept');
             store_dept.load();
```

The problem comes when i hit  generate letter button, the id's of  the checked rows(1,2,3)  comes like 0,1,1,2 when it must come like 0,1,2,3 in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you use `get` method of `MixedCollection` while you should use `itemAt`. In api you can read that this method returns the item associated with the passed key (id in your case) OR index and that key has priority over index. So when you pass 0 then this is treated as index, because you don't have such key and for that index id is 1. But when you pass 1 then it is treated as key (id in other words) so it returns item with id 1.

Replace `alert("id "+sm_dept.selections.get(j).data.id);` with `alert("id "+sm_dept.selections.itemAt(j).data.id);` and you'll be good.